# How do I perform COUNT & SUM operations with 'DBAccess'iOS ORM

Tags: ios, objective-c, orm, dbaccess

I am using DBAccess framework v1.6.12 with Xcode 7.0.1.

I would like to select a SUM and COUNT of two properties, much like the query below, except the ORM does not have a raw SQL interface:

```
SELECT
  SUM(bed_in_datetime - bed_out_datetime) AS sum_bed_in
 ,COUNT(bed_in_datetime) AS cnt_bed_in
FROM
 sleep_tbl;
```

Is there a way I can achieve it using `DBAccess`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no concept of SELECT as such with the ORM, because you're dealing with entire class objects and not SQL, however the DBQuery object does have methods on it for `SUM`, `COUNT`, `GROUP BY` & `IDs` that return subsets of data from a query.

This would have to be done in two stages, but shouldn't have a huge affect on the time take to perform the query.

But the first element will be performed like this:

```
double sum = [[sleep_tbl query] sumOf:@"(bed_in_datetime - bed_out_datetime)"];
```

And the count like this:

```
int count = [[sleep_tbl query] count];
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  
DBAccess version was my typo.  I am using not 1.6.2 but 1.6.12.  
Okay, I will try to use sumOf method and count method.

Comment: For search efficiency, can I use the `view` ?

Comment: No, there are no views in DBAccess.  For efficiency? do you mean returning just a subset of data to use less memory?  Because if so, that is - (DBResultSet*)fetchLightweightPrefetchingProperties:(NSArray*)properties;`.  This selects the properties you specify only, and any access to other properties are then queried when required.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
My goal is to get the monthly average like: `SELECT AVERAGE(a-b), AVERAGE(c-d), AVERAGE(e-f), AVERAGE(g-h) FROM sleep_tbl WHERE year=2015 AND month=10;`
Could you have any hints for me?

Comment: For that,  I would maintain an averages table.  Or you could divide the SUM by the count which would still be fairly fast.! As you already have both parts already.

Comment: All right. I will use following query for each parameter. `DBQuery *query = [[sleep_tbl query] where:xxx]; average = [query sumOf:sumOfExpression] / [query count];`

Comment: Yes,  at present that would seem the best option.